# Vertical placement of math symbol in LaTeX

Tags: latex

I'm using the symbol `\otimes` as a unary operator and it's vertical alignment doesn't seem right to me. It wants to sit a bit below the baseline. For example, if I define `\newcommand{\myop}{\ensuremath \otimes}`, then `$\myop I$` becomes

[image: Operator below the baseline]

and `$F_{\myop I}$` becomes

[image: Operator misaligned in subscript]

I tried using `\raisebox` to fix this, e.g.,

```
\newcommand{\myop}{\ensuremath \raisebox{1pt}{$\otimes$}}
```

This fixes `$\myop I$`:

[image: Operator near baseline]

But `\raisebox` doesn't seem to be sensitive to subscripts. The operator stays the same size while everything around it shrinks:

[image: Operator too big in subscript]

The problem, I think, is that `\raisebox` creates its own LR box, which doesn't inherit the settings in the surrounding math environment. Is there a version of `\raisebox` that "respects math"?

Comment: @Closing fanatic: no, the consensus is that it belongs right here.

Comment: Yeah, I would note that I checked this Meta post before asking the question: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12918/can-we-have-a-ruling-on-latex-on-stackoverflow You should do so too before voting to close.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try `\mathchoice` (or `\mathpalette`):

```
\newcommand{\myop}{%
  \mathchoice{\raisebox{1pt}{$\displaystyle\otimes$}}
             {\raisebox{1pt}{$\otimes$}}
             {\raisebox{0.5pt}{$\scriptstyle\otimes$}}
             {\raisebox{0.2pt}{$\scriptscriptstyle\otimes$}}}
```

The [amsopn documentation](http://tug.org/texlive/Contents/live/texmf-dist/doc/latex/amsmath/amsopn.pdf) says:

> ... the vertical spacing may not be optimal in script and scriptscript
>   sizes. Unfortunately TeX provides no easy way to do math mode vertical spacing
>   that varies with current math style like mu units.

Comment: `\mathchoice` seems to be just the thing. But I can't find the documentation for it in Google... Pointers?

Comment: The TeXbook, p. 151. See http://tug.ctan.org/cgi-bin/ctanPackageInformation.py?id=texbook for the source code.

Comment: @Chris: Extex's Javadocs have surprisingly good documentation of Tex primitives.  For `\mathchoice`, see http://www.extex.org/snapshot/javadoc/org/extex/unit/tex/math/Mathchoice.html

Answer (score 2):

```
$F_{\raisebox{1pt}{\scriptsize$\otimes$} I}$
```

Comment: This works, sure, but I want to be able to put it in a macro that will work in any context. E.g., `\newcommand{\myop}{\ensuremath ... \otimes ... }`

Comment: Edited the question to respond to this.